# How to remove row in Cassandra via thrift-client?

Tags: c++, cassandra, thrift

I'm tring to delete a key from a column family using thrift-client(C++) but the only thing I could do is removing a cell.

Can anybody help me please?

That's what I tried but it delete only one cell:

```
string key = "key";
ColumnOrSuperColumn csc;
csc.__isset.column = true;
ColumnPath cpath;

cpath.column_family.assign("users");
cpath.__isset.column = true;
cpath.column="id";
//_client is org::apache::cassandra::CassandraClient
_client->get(csc, key, cpath, org::apache::cassandra::ConsistencyLevel::ONE);
_client->remove(key, cpath, csc.column.timestamp,org::apache::cassandra::ConsistencyLevel::ONE);
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Do you have some code you can show us?

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify a column name in your `cpath`,so it will delete an entire row. Take a look at http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/API10#remove

Comment: which timestamp should I use?

Comment: Well, generally you should you a current time in millis
http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/API10#Column

Comment: Can you give me an exemple how to fix that please?